# Enter Tab Name In Cell To Calculate Sum of Column or Range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have seen one other similar question on this topic posted a few years ago, but I have been unable to have any success with the suggestions given there.

I have sales sheets (a new one added each day) with standardized names (12.3.18, 12.4.18, 12.5.18, etc..) that I would like to be able to see the sales sums of on a separate cover sheet. Ideally I'd just like to be able to enter a date into a given cell (A3) and have the sum calculated for that date.

For example entering:

```
=sum('12.20.18'!H2:H99)
```

works fine, but when I try:

```
=sum(indirect(A3!H2:H99)
```

I get #REF!

I have tried playing around with the code (adding apostrophes, and parantheses), but haven't had any luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
=sum(indirect(A3 & “!H2:H99”))
```